# rails 3.0 exception handling in middleware

Tags: exception, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3.0, I'm trying to get exception handling around middleware code. Specifically, if a request comes in with a content-type: application/json  but an invalid json input, rails currently renders public/500.html - which is unfortunate.

Since this isn't in a controller yet, most of the things I've seen don't work/apply.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue from the Exceptions thrown and decide what to do:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_exception

def render_exception
  # examine the Exception here
  # and decide which template to render
  render :template => "shared/???.html", :status => ???, :layout => 'error' 
end
```

Place this code in the app/controllers/application_controller.rb

I hope this is kind of what you're looking for ...